# HTML::TagFilter returning HTML::Element HASH object

Tags: html, perl

New to Perl and I am digging what I can do as well as the support and documentation available for all these great libraries; however, I am having an issue with a script I am working on.  Prior to implementing HTML::TagFilter, I was using line 63 (print FH $tree->as_HTML) to print to file the html content I was looking for.  I looked specifically for everything in the body tag.  Now I'd like to only print out the p tags, h tags, and img tags without any attributes.  When I run my code, the files are created in the proper directory but in each file a hash object is printed (HTML::Element=HASH(0x3a104c8)).

```
use open qw(:locale);
use strict;
use warnings qw(all);

use HTML::TreeBuilder 5 -weak; # Ensure weak references in use
use URI::Split qw/ uri_split uri_join /;
use HTML::TagFilter;

my @links;

open(FH, "<", "index/site-index.txt")
    or die "Failed to open file: $!\n";
while(<FH>) { 
    chomp; 
    push @links, $_;
} 
close FH;

my $dir = "";
while($dir eq ""){
print "What is the name of the site we are working on? ";
$dir = <STDIN>;
chomp $dir; 
}

#make directory to store files
mkdir($dir);

my $entities = "";
my $indent_char = "\t";
my $filter = HTML::TagFilter->new(
    allow=>{ p => { none => [] }, h1 => { none => [] }, h2 => { none => [] }, h3 => { none => [] }, h4 => { none => [] }, h5 => { none => [] }, h6 => { none => [] }, img => { none => [] },  },
    log_rejects => 1,
    strip_comments => 1
    );

 foreach my $url (@links){

    #print $url;

    my ($filename) = $url =~ m#([^/]+)$#;

    #print $filename;
    $filename =~ tr/=/_/;
    $filename =~ tr/?/_/;
    #print "\n";

    my $currentfile = $dir . '/' . $filename . '.html';

    print "Preparing " . $currentfile . "\n" . "\n";

    open (FH, '>', $currentfile)
        or die "Failed to open file: $!\n";


    my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_url($url);
    $tree->parse($url);
    $tree = $tree->look_down('_tag', 'body');
    if($tree){
        $tree->dump; # a method we inherit from HTML::Element
        print FH $filter->filter($tree);
        #print FH $tree->as_HTML($entities, $indent_char), "\n";
    } else{
        warn "No body tag found";
    }

    print "File " . $currentfile . " completed.\n" . "\n";

    close FH;

}
```

Why is this happening and how can I print the actual content I am looking for?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$filter->filter()` expects HTML, `HTML::TreeBuilder` is not HTML, but a subclass of `HTML::Element`. `look_down()` returns a `HTML::Element`. That is what you see from your print, because when you treat this reference as a string, you will get the string representation of the object. `HTML::Element=HASH(0x7f81509ab6d8)`, which means that the object `HTML::Element`, which is solved by a `HASH` structure and the memory address of this object.

You can fix it all by calling filter with the HTML from the look_down:

```
         print FH $filter->filter($tree->as_HTML);
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you so much for your help!  I knew there was something more I needed to do.  It makes sense now why the object was printing vs the content within it.  Thanks again!